# Raspbian + usb card reader + sd card

Tags: sd-card

My issue: I have a raspi 2, with working, fresh Raspbian. I attached a USB card reader and put in an SD card (which contains another Raspbian/Raspberry Pi image), but I can't figure out how to reach the SD card in the reader.

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a2c:0002  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0158 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 2.0 multicard reader
```

And then, fdisk:

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 7964 MB, 7964983296 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 243072 cylinders, total 15556608 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1            2048      131071       64512    e  W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2          131072    15556607     7712768   83  Linux
```

The SD card in the reader contains a corrupted fs (too much power-down), which I would like to try to fix/repair.

Any ideas on how to reach the SD card? (Or any ideas why I can't find it anywhere).
All ideas welcome (I think that I just missed something and that is why I can't see it).

Comment: @Milliways, I don't understand your criticism of the OP's English. Some of the verbs are the wrong tense but for someone who may not be a native English speaker, the question is very reasonablely asked. I really don't understand your comment about inventing new names. I recommend you edit your comment to remove the non-helpful commentary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your multi-card reader should show up as either one or multiple block devices, starting with `/dev/sda`, et cetera. You may check which devices are present using `ls /dev/sd?`. Also, you still should see your mSD card with its partitions show up when doing `sudo fdisk -l`.

I've seen different card readers working slightly differently, so it may be that while multiple `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb` are visible when you do an `ls /dev/sd?`, the exact name depends on which kind of card you stuck into which socket of your card reader.

Please note that `/dev/sda` is the whole storage device, such as an SD or mSD card. `/dev/sda1` is its first partition, and so on.

Comment: Seems the card more damaged then as I expected, because it's not show up at all. Should show up in fdisk list ?

Comment: I've checked with a Pi Zero W I have over here and an OTG card reader: yes, your mSD card should show up when you do `sudo fdisk -l`. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much. My card do not show up, could be dead or the driver is not perfect. I will test on different machine then. Thank you again.

Comment: I don't have auto mounting, using only command line. So fdisk shows non-mounted partitions.

Comment: The man page for `fdisk` (https://linux.die.net/man/8/fdisk) has to say about `-l`: "List the partition tables for the specified devices and then exit. If no devices are given, those mentioned in /proc/partitions (if that exists) are used."